# parsing XML with element tree python 2.7

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Why is this not accepting **i** as a variable in my for loop?  here is my code:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/comments_42.xml'

while True:
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)

    counts = tree.findall('.//count')
    print "counts[0] = ", counts[0]
    print "counts[0].text = ", counts[0].text
    print "type(int(counts[0].text)) = ", type(int(counts[0].text))
    total = 0
    for i in counts:
        total = total + int(counts[i].text)
    print total
    break
```

I get the following output:
[image]

A sample of the XML I want to parse is here:
[image]

Im trying to add up the "count"s in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counts` - is an array of elements. Here `for i in counts:` `i` will be an element. You can write like that

```
for elem in counts:
    total += int(elem.text)
```

or

```
for index in range(0, len(counts)):
    total += int(counts[index].text)
```